# What is the easiest way to achieve parallelization of gridded/looped processes in C++

Tags: c++, parallel-processing

Everything I describe is currently occurring in a hydrologic model I am building.

I have some for loops that control the reading of input data across gridded data sets.   The initial inputs can be anywhere from 100x100 to 3000x3000 cells.  After reading in these inputs, I perform some initial calculations (5-10) across the grid. (See my question here for questions I have related to reading in the inputs: http://bit.ly/1AkyzWy).  After the initial calculations, I enter a mode where I step "into" each cell and run 4-15 processes.  Each cell has a different subset of roughly 15 processes - some of these cells are identical with others in terms of the processes that are run, and no cell runs a subset that doesn't exist elsewhere.  A time step consists of one complete loop through all of the cells.  I run anywhere from 30 to 15,000 time steps.

And no here's the important part, I think: Each cell depends on the results of the processes run in the neighboring cells, but not during each time step.  Within a time step, when in a cell, the current running processes are referencing the results of the processes run in the neighboring cells during the previous timestep.  Nothing within a cell depends on the processes run in a neighboring cell during the same timestep.

So, I think my program, which can take an hour or so to run 1500 time steps on 1000x10000 cells, is ripe for parallelization.  I've done initial research into this, I'm worried about solutions affecting portability and performance on different end-users machines.

Does an easy to implement solution exist that doesn't affect portability and adapts to different users' number of computer cores?

Comment: I'd look into using the GPU (graphics card). There are many libraries that support that. Since your program seems similar to Conway's Game of Life in its requirements, I'd google that together with GPU or library name results from googling ... so on, you'll just have to wing it (the googling).

Comment: Which hardware do you plan to use?

Comment: I use an Intel i7-5550U processor which uses two cores and another processor (I can't remember exactly) that has 8 cores.  But this program will be released to the wild to be used by whomever wishes, so I have no idea how their computers will be set up.